# meteor and textareas

Tags: meteor

Ok so I'm not sure why I can't render the code. First if I console.log users.content I get the content I want but I'm some how not able to pass it to a textarea so that it show's it...

```
Users = new Meteor.Collection("users");

if(Meteor.is_client){
  Template.inputUser.code = function(){
    var el = Users.find({name:"oscar"});
    el.forEach(function(users){
      console.log(users.content);
    })
  }
}
```

And then on my html template I have

```
<body>{{> inputUser}}</body>

<template name="inputUser">
<textarea>{{content}}</textarea>
</template>
```

And I would have a record on the db suck as so

```
if(Meteor.is_server)
  Users.insert({name:"oscar",content:"hello world"})
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your method `Template.inputUser.code` should return something, you should also note that it wouldn't be called with that template either as it needs a `{{code}}` call in it rather than `{{content}}`

The second point is database contents are not always available if you have disabled the autopublish package, if so check out using publish(in the server code) and subscribe(in the client code): http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe you can use this to check when the client has all the data to display. Something like:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allusers', function() {
  Template.inputUser.code = function(){
    var user = Users.findOne({name:"oscar"});
    return user.content;
  }
});

...

Meteor.publish('allusers', function() {
  return Users.find();
});
```